# Can lasers be used for weather detection along an aircraft's flight path?

Tags: commercial-aviation, weather, radar

Aircraft use RADAR for weather detection such as storm clouds, rain, etc. Why don't they use LASER instead to measure the density of the weather ahead?

RADAR has been known to return false signals of weather ahead (i.e. clear cloud, low density).

Would LASER be a more accurate application as LASER has been used in many other areas such as measuring terrain topography, density of some materials, temperature, etc.

P.S  Please forgive my ignorance if this technology is already in use for this application.

Comment: [LIDAR](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23402/how-does-radar-detect-turbulence-and-wind-speed/23551#23551) are generally on the ground, but as this answer says, there are experimentations for airborne LIDAR to [detect CAT](http://www.dlr.de/dlr/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-10081/151_read-7615/year-all/#/gallery/11637).

Comment: not at 35,000ft looking for weather hazards...LASER operates in many wavelengths of light.Some of which is not visible to the eye without equipment and media such as glasses and or vapour such as smoke,etc.

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19431/8730)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not appear to be relevant to aviation weather.  Such a question is general meteorological science.  To make sure I am completely clear, this would not be unlike asking a materials science question simply because it may be incorporated into the body of an aircraft.